# 3d print first or board design?

Tags: 3d-design

I am trying to make a controller(Who doesn't want that?) for PC. Just before starting the build I wondered if it would be hard to 3D print to scale of my board. So I was stuck in a paradox... 3D print first or PCB board design first?

---

#### Cons: PCB design first

1. Building to scale is difficult
2. Parts may not line up

#### Cons: 3D print first

1. Eagle design needs precise measurements
2. PCB may not fit correctly

Which is better to do first?

Comment: This might be the wrong forum. Please inform if so.

Comment: The question is not very clear, but without a printer you cannot print any object, so cutting from cardboard would be an option if you want to look at the size. Generally, people buy their controller boards.

Comment: Im designing my own ... have both ready but wondering which to do first so i edit the other later

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing! I'm no expert, but would highly suggest doing the PCB design first and get a working prototype. Redesigning a 3D print to accommodate the PCB seems far easier than the other way around.

Comment: Board first and enclosure second. Seems the most sensible, **unless** you are constrained primarily by size. However, even so, it seems sensible to get the board working first, with space for all of the components required and then make the case.